# Error: deploying Rails 2.3.8 app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Would appreciate any insight into how to get my Rails 2.3.8 deployed using Heroku. I am getting the following error message when I try to push to push to heroku:

```
    git push heroku master
    Enter passphrase:
    Counting objects:3, done.
    Compressing objects: 100 % (2/2), done.
    Writing onject: 100 % (3/3), 4.34 KiB, done.
    Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

    -----> Heroku receiving push
    Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

    To git@heroku.com: falling-sunrise.git
    [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:falling-sunrise.git'
```

I have also attached the actual screenshot of my command line screen.  I read somewhere that I may have to write a gemfile to get the push to work. I also did that and added it to the root of my app but no luck.

Comment: Guys Thank you for the help. Just figured out what was wrong. I was never actually pushing the rails app!!!!  I am new to Git and did not realize you need to git add each file before you can commit them

Comment: Note that if you're lazy, and are sure your tests are passing, you can just `git commit -a -m "commit message here"` to commit all modified and new files in the working directory. Useful if you just changed a bunch of files, and/or regenerated some static content.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the layout of your app? Make sure to run `bundle install` locally and to check your Gemfile; it may not be configured correctly, or you haven't added it the new files (including the ever-important `Gemfile.lock`) to git.

Also see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails_2x_applications

Comment: my layout looks like this:
   -.git
   -app
   -config
   -console
   -db
   -doc
   -Gemfile
   -Gemfile.lock
   -lib
   -log
   -public
   -Rakefile
   -README
   -script
   -test
   -tmp
   -vendor

Comment: And i ran bundle install after writing the gemfile. and pushed all the new files to git

Answer (score 0):

try bundling your gemfile and making sure it's complete. If that doesn't work, you might try pushing your app to a bamboo stack:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bamboo

Comment: Note that you cannot migrate *from* Cedar to Bamboo. You would need to create a new app on the Bamboo stack.

Comment: this time I tried pushing app to a bamboo stack and received different error:  "Heroku push rejected, no Rails or Rack app detected

Comment: It's still the "same" error - Heroku doesn't know how to handle your app. But it looks like you sorted it.